# Search function for a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a simple table ([Link to Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cnuRqMDrkCd6bFAe2LZ0zZrpwJXmk976IchFBavpoEA/edit?usp=sharing)) with 3 columns and multiple rows. Column 1 is Location like "a" or "b", column 2 is for start of a number range like 100, and column 3 is for the end of the number range like 200. I need to know which formula I could use that would return the result of a certain Location based on which number was typed in. For instance if I type in 123 the result should return the value of Location "b". Please look at the table to understand more about what I am needing help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question from another user on a different website. The formula of =INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(B9,B2:B5,1)) works like a charm.